# Include generic sass file in every file without @import with webpack 2

Tags: webpack, sass

At the moment, I am having to add the following declaration in every sass file:

```
@import '../src/styles/index';
```

My sass files are generally in the same folder as my components so the relative path will be different a lot of the time.

Is there anyway using webpack that I can have the import added without having to declare it on every single file?

Comment: Why not just include it in your variables file?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change the order of imports in .scss files.

Let me give you example. Variables are something that also need to be available in every other .scss file. The way I set my styles is to import all .scss partials in main index.scss. The first imported partial in index.scss is just a file with all variables. These variables are then accessible in all partials listed below variables import in index.scss.